# Mageplaza extension can't be deployed - Use of undefined constant

Tags: magento2, deployment, mageplaza

I'm having trouble deploying a MagePlaza extension (SEO) to my staging environment on Magento Cloud even though it works perfectly fine on my machine. I'm getting this message:

[image]

Comment: This is a question for Mageplaza support - they will be more than happy to assist you.

Comment: Best thing to do is to have mageplaza fix it, but otherwise you could correct it yourself.

Comment: Hey I'm facing the exact same issue. Did you get any resolution?